New relic TraceId Not getting poplulated in ASP.NET Core middleware
I am trying to access the newrelic traceid  in ASP.NET Core middleware and pass it as a response header in the response.
Please see the implementation below :
public sealed class TraceIdMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private readonly ILogger<TraceIdMiddleware> _logger;

    public TraceIdMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILogger<TraceIdMiddleware> logger)
    {
        _next = next;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Headers.ContainsKey("X-Trace-Id"))
        {
            var tracer = NewRelic.Api.Agent.NewRelic.GetAgent();
            var traceId = tracer.TraceMetadata.TraceId;
           
            _logger.LogWarning("NewRelic Trace Id " + traceId);
            _logger.LogWarning("Http context trace Id " + context.TraceIdentifier);
          
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(traceId))
            {
                context.Response.Headers.Append("X-Trace-Id", traceId);
            }
        }

        await _next(context);
    }
}

But the trace id is always returned as empty. The agent is running and distributed tracing is enabled, still the issue persist.
Has anyone encountered this issue?

After debugging the issue, I found the reason is not set the Environment variables.
Please check the official doc: Environment variables for .NET Core.
We can verify it/or find more via checking the logs, you can find it in this path C:\ProgramData\New Relic\.NET Agent\Logs.

